# White Blank Screen in Ionic on Arabic Translation

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-translate

I am developing an Ionic app in which I am also using angular-translate lib. The app works in all views in English but when I switch to Arabic, on some views it work fine but on some of the views show a white blank screen after a blink of the original view with nothing in console.

It is very strange when i click on inspect element, the view appears and there is a white flash when switching from one view to another.

It only happens when I select Arabic as a language. It works fine in English lang.

What could be the possible reason and how can I overcome it?

PS. I have whitelist installed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after installing the apk file on my real live mobile device, the blank white screen was coming and nothing else appear ! then I saved the translate library JS file to my local ionic project and changed on **index.html** :

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bower-angular-translate/2.0.1/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="lib/translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i had the same issue and solved by that way. if this answer solved your problem, plz vote-up and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for an answer to this, I have also tried putting all my translations in arrays too and skipped angular-translate altogether

Answer (score 0):

I had the same blank screen and when I touch the location of a button or an input box, the whole view is shown.

my problem was not related to external libraries but I had style.css having this

```
body{direction: rtl;}
```

I changed it to be specific to the form tag only and the blank page disapeared